# What's the difference between : and = in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry if the title is rather confusing, but I'm curious to know the difference between these two lines:

```
var title = String()
var title: String
```

Is one being initialized and one only be declared? Which is more correct?

For example, if I have a struct should I use one of the other?

So the reason I ask this is because I'm learning about how to grab some JSON from a url and then display it in my app. One of the new ways of doing so is using Decodable. So, I have a struct in a model class like so:

```
struct Videos: Decodable {

    var title = String()
    var number_of_views : Int
    var thumbnail_image_name: String
    var channel: Channel
    var duration: Int

}
```

In another class I have this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data,response,error) in

            if(error != nil){
                print(error!)
                return
            }

        guard let data = data else { return }


        do{
            self.Videos2 = try JSONDecoder().decode([Videos].self, from: data)

            //self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        }catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()
```

So, should I declare or initialize the variables in my struct? I'm assuming I should just declare them like so:
    var title: String?
Would that be the correct syntax in my struct?

UPDATE:
I understand this question was more broad then I originally proposed it to be. I'm sorry about that, but thank you so much for all your great answers that clarified a lot up for me.

Comment: In your `Videos` example (which really should be called `Video`, not `Videos`), I would not use `var title = String()`. Assuming the title is always going to be decoded, why initialize it to an empty length string first, when that's always going to be replaced with the real title soon thereafter. That's just inefficient and is a poor design. Use `var title: String`, unless you have some reason why you cannot.

Comment: Unrelated to your "should I initialize to an empty string before setting it to its real value" question, you should ask yourself why you're using `var` instead of `let`. Always favor immutability over mutability. It simplifies your code.

Comment: Ok, great! Yeah, I'm sorry the answer somewhat diverted away from the original. Does {var title: String} get declared as an optional or do I have to add the question mark? Also, in this case should I add the question mark or not? I understand the question mark says "This variable could be optional meaning it could possibly be nil so make sure to check before using" I guess that would depend on the JSON I receive. Oh my, I've now asked about 5 questions in one...

Comment: When adopting `Decodable` a protocol extension provides an `init` method which fulfills the rule to initialize all properties so declaring them is sufficient.

Comment: So then my question still stands. Should I add a question mark to end of each?

Comment: Is the field always present in the JSON? Is the field required? Then, no, it would be wrong to declare it as optional by including the `?`. But, if it _is_ optional, then include the `?`.

Comment: If the JSON sends all keys in every item in the array then No. Use non-optional types as much as possible.

Comment: Understood. So let's say it's a form that requires a user to enter in some info. And some of that info is optional(Eg. Phone number, email, etc.). At this point, I should include the question mark in that case? Would the JSON just be an empty string or something for those variables? As in, the user didn't provide an email so I received an empty string in that JSON field?

Comment: "I've now asked about 5 questions in one" ... And that's not a good thing. That's the very definition of a question that is too broad.

Comment: @Rob Understood, I will keep it more specific next time. Thank you.

Comment: @Rob Hey everyone, I'm very sorry about the broad question that I had asked. I should have stuck with my original question, but it snowballed from there. I kept having more questions to the answers that were being provided.

Comment: Well, I give you credit for taking the feedback constructively. It’s too easy to take it personally and get upset. I suspect you’re going to become a valuable contributor to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Rob And I appreciate that and hope so as well! I'm not sure if you were one of the people to downvote my question, but do you think you could change that to an upvote?

Comment: @humbleCoder - I did not down-vote your question. I made my point and saw no need to "pile on". But at the same time, with no offense intended, I'm not going to up-vote it as I don't think this question "shows research effort; is useful and clear". Bottom line, I'd suggest you don't worry about this question any more and just move on. I'm sure that with your constructive perspective, you'll quickly recover any "reputation" points by posting good answers to other people's questions, or posting your own well-researched questions (that aren't too broad, are not duplicative, etc.). Best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `:` defines the type of your variable, whereas `=` assigns an actual value to the variable.

So:

```
var title = String()
```

This calls the initializer of the `String` type, creating a new `String` instance. It then assigns this value to `title`. The type of `title` is inferred to be `String` because you're assigning an object of type `String` to it; however, you could also write this line explicitly as:

```
var title: String = String()
```

This would mean you are declaring a `title` variable of type `String`, and assigning a new `String` to it.

```
var title: String
```

This simply says you're defining a variable of type `String`. However, you are not assigning a value to it. You will need to assign something to this variable before you use it, or you will get a compile error (and if this is a property rather than just a variable, you'll need to assign it before you get to the end of your type's `init()` method, unless it's optional with `?` after it, in which case it gets implicitly initialized to `nil`).

EDIT: For your example, I'd probably declare all the variables using `let` and `:`, assuming that your JSON provides values for all of those properties. The initializer generated by `Decodable` should then set all the properties when you create the object. So, something like:

```
struct Videos: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let number_of_views : Int
    let thumbnail_image_name: String
    let channel: Int
    let duration: Int
}
```

Comment: Awesome, now lets say(hypothetically) I don't know what my JSON response will be. As in, a variable I'm being passed could be nil. Should I add a question mark at the end each of my variables?

Comment: "...a variable I'm being passed could be nil. Should I add a question mark at the end each of my variables?" Yes, that is the whole point of making a variable an Optional. It makes it possible to be either empty (nil) or contain a value.

Comment: Hey everyone, I'm very sorry about the broad question that I had asked. I should have stuck with my original question, but it snowballed from there. I kept having more questions to the answers that were being provided.

Answer (score 2):

This initializes a value

```
var title = String()
```

This declares a value but does not initialize it

```
var title: String
```

If you attempt to use the latter, such as `print(title)`, you will get a compiler error stating `Variable 'title' used before being initialized`

It does not matter whether the value is a class or a struct.

The `=` operator is the *assignment operator*, it assigns a value to the object on the left of the `=`

Typically, class or struct properties are declared but not initialized until the `init()` is called. A simple class might be

```
class MyClass {
    let myProperty: String

    init(aString: String) {
        self.myProperty = aString
    }
}
```

Whereas inside the scope of a function you may declare a local variable that only lives inside the scope of the function.

```
func doSomethingToAString(aString: String) -> String {
    let extraString = "Something"
    let amendedString = aString + extraString
    return amendedString
}
```

In your specific example, the struct synthesizes an initializer that will allow you to initialize the struct with all the values needed to fill your properties. The initializer generated by `Decodable` should then set all the properties when you create a Videos struct, you will do it something like:

```
let aVideos = Videos(title: "My Title", number_of_views: 0, thumbnail_image_name: "ImageName", channel: Channel(), duration: 10)
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Could give me an example in your answer of when you would use one over the other?

Comment: @humbleCoder Check my answer for an example.

Comment: @humbleCoder - You use the former if you need it initialized with an empty string (which is rarely the case). You use the latter if you will be initializing it with some value (e.g. in `init` or whatever).

Comment: Hey everyone, I'm very sorry about the broad question that I had asked. I should have stuck with my original question, but it snowballed from there. I kept having more questions to the answers that were being provided.

Answer (score 1):

> Is one being initialized and one only be declared?

Yes, meaning that the declared cannot be used. If you tried to set a value for it, you would get a compile-time error:

```
variable 'title' passed by reference before being initialized
```

> Which is more correct?

There is no rule of thumb to determine which is more correct, that would be depends on is there a need to initialize `title` directly.

On another hand, when it comes to declare properties for a class, saying `var title = String()` means that you are give `title` an initial value ("") which means that you are able to create an instance of this class directly, example:

```
class Foo {
    var title = String()
}

let myFoo = Foo()
```

However, if `title` declared as `var title: String`, you will have to implement the `init` for `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
    var title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

let myFoo = Foo(title: "")
```

---

Also, you have an option to declare it as *lazy*:

```
lazy var title = String()
```

which means:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not
>   calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored
>   property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.
>   <sub>[Properties - Lazy Stored Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)</sub>

Comment: Hey everyone, I'm very sorry about the broad question that I had asked. I should have stuck with my original question, but it snowballed from there. I kept having more questions to the answers that were being provided.